# mysqlimport: Error: 1227 Access denied with MySQL 8.0 and Amazon RDS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, mysql-8.0, mysqlimport

We are using MySQL 8.0.* and .csv file for the importing data into Amazon RDS. We are executing this command from the app server command line.

**Error:**

```
mysqlimport: Error: 1227 Access denied; you need (at least one of) the SUPER, SYSTEM_VARIABLES_ADMIN or SESSION_VARIABLES_ADMIN privilege(s) for this operation
```

**Command:**

```
mysqlimport --local --compress --columns='col1,col2,col3,col4' -h dbhost -u dbusername -pdbpassword dbname --fields-terminated-by='|' file_path/table_name.csv
```

*We have already provided DBA permission to DB user.*

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As error suggests, the user you are running import command not having permissions `SESSION_VARIABLES_ADMIN`.

You could setup it like below.

```
GRANT SESSION_VARIABLES_ADMIN ON *.* TO 'user'@'%';
```

OR

```
GRANT SESSION_VARIABLES_ADMIN ON *.* TO 'user'@'specific-host';
```

It should resolve the issue.

Comment: I get 'You are not allowed to create a user with Grant'.

Comment: @RodrikTheReader you may need to ask your database administrator to run this command for you.

Answer (score -1):

Comment out the parameters TEMP_LOG_BIN and GTID_PURGED in the mysql dump and save. Try to import the dump file in target DB. It should work.